# the things that money can not buy vs the things that we can not buy things with money

Tags: word-order, negation, construction

> 1. The things that money can not buy
> 2. The things that we can not buy with money
> 3. The things that money cannot be bought

What is the difference between these phrase
phrase and clause ? Can money  be used as a subject ?

Answer (score 1):

Your third sentence is incorrect

> The things that money cannot be bought.

you might mean

> The things that cannot be bought with money.

All three mean there are certain things in the world which do not have a monetary value
and can be referred to as **priceless**.

Phrasing in your first sentence tends to mean idealistic things can not be bought like love, friendship, loyalty, the dew on a flower petal in the morning.

Phrasing in the second sentence may imply there is a different way to "pay" for *something* other than money and, at least for me, is used for more materialistic things.

**money** can easily be used as the subject

> Money can not buy these things.